python code for getTopSellingProducts call within Ebay Merchandising SDK problems
I get a valid response when I run:
from ebaysdk.merchandising import Connection as Merchandising
try:
    api = Merchandising(appid="YOUR_APPID", config_file=None)
    response = api.execute('getMostWatchedItems', {'maxResults': 10})
    print(response.dict())
    print(response.reply)
except ConnectionError as e:
    print(e)
    print(e.response.dict())

But If I try to adjust this for the getTopSellingProducts call by changing the response line to:
response = api.execute('getTopSellingProducts', {'maxResults': 10})

I get error:

ebaysdk.exception.ConnectionError: 'getTopSellingProducts: Not Found'

But as far as I can tell from the SDK (https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/wiki/Merchandising-API-Class) this should be supported.
Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong please?  I can't really understand the eBay API reference material.
I'm pretty new to API's and have been working my way through some examples that don't require any authorisation to get started, but then wanted to progress to something more interesting.  I'm now pretty confident I have my keys set up as I'm able to get a good response from the first example above.
I've tried using ChatGPT to help out also but that's sending me in circles.
Update:26 May.
Today I have tried using a more direct API call approach, but I still am having problems.
When I use:
url = "https://svcs.ebay.com/MerchandisingService?OPERATION-NAME=getMostWatchedItems&REST-PAYLOAD"
headers = {
'SERVICE-NAME':'MerchandisingService', 
"SERVICE-VERSION": "1.1.0",
"CONSUMER-ID": "<my APP ID>",
"RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT":"XML",
"maxResults": "3"}

Then the response works fine.
But If I replace "getMostWatchedItems" with "getTopSellingProducts" then I get a 404.
When I look at the ebay provided samples for HTML for both calls they look almost identical so I don't know what the problem is.
getMostWatchedItems sample:
https://svcs.ebay.com/MerchandisingService?
   OPERATION-NAME=getMostWatchedItems
   &SERVICE-NAME=MerchandisingService
   &SERVICE-VERSION=1.1.0
   &CONSUMER-ID=YourAppID
   &RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML
   &REST-PAYLOAD
   &categoryId=267

getTopSellingProducts sample:
https://svcs.ebay.com/MerchandisingService?
   OPERATION-NAME=getTopSellingProducts&
   SERVICE-NAME=MerchandisingService&
   SERVICE-VERSION=1.1.0&
   CONSUMER-ID=YourAppID&
   RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&
   REST-PAYLOAD&
   maxResults=3


How do you know "getTopSellingProducts" is a supported attribute to "api.execute"?

Actually - I thought I saw that in the SDK notes, but now I can't find it again - so maybe I imagined it!  I've been trying another method today so will add that to the desciption

I'm having this exact problem too and have found this note written in the merchandisingService.wsdl
Important: This API call is no longer actively managed and cannot be relied upon to retrieve current product data, and in some cases, will not retrieve any data. As an alternative to this call, we recommend using the https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/marketing/resources/merchandised_product/methods/getMerchandisedProducts getMerchandisedProducts call of the
Buy Marketing API
